# Scanning of barcode not letting user move barcode scans twice

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I am using zxing scanner and it works great but for some reason it's scanning the same barcode twice. I have put a thread delay in to try to keep the view port open but allow the operator time to move the device away from the bar code but no luck they are reporting its scanning the item twice but yet we dont want to close the view port.

But to add I dont want to close ZXingScannerView just pause it to give the user enough time to get the next barcode ready

The below code is under the button click of a button their not tapping the button twice its the scann even is hapeneing twice.

```
ZXingDefaultOverlay overlay;        
ZXingScannerView zxing;  
zxing = new ZXingScannerView
{
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
};


zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{               

    BarCode = result.Text;

    await PlayBeep();
    await Task.Delay(2000); //This is the delay I was given so that it would not scan right away again but leave the view open
    overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
        {
            TopText = "Hold your phone up to the barcode",
            BottomText = "Scanning will happen automatically",
            ShowFlashButton = zxing.HasTorch,
            AutomationId = "zxingDefaultOverlay",

        };
        var grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        grid.Children.Add(zxing);
        grid.Children.Add(overlay);

        // The root page of your application
        Content = grid;
}
```

Comment: It's most likely a terrible hack (no Xamarin experience here), but you could move your anonymous OnScanResult handler to a separate method and register the method as handler. Then comes the hacky part: inside the method _de_register the handler at the start, do the scan, then delay and before the end of the method re-register the handler.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel thanks mark I will wait for a few more replies first but I do get what you saying but you need to use the Device invoke so you do to do that

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I should have said this is on a button click

Comment: @MarkusDeibel does the constructer get called twice in xamrain forms ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, you can use the zxing options function  DelayBetweenContinuousScans

```
zxing = new ZXingScannerView
{
     HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
     VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
     AutomationId = "zxingScannerView",
};
zxing.Options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
{
  DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 2000
};
```

Comment: Hi , remenmber to mark answer later when have time .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT done sorry have been a bit busy in new job.

Answer (score -1):

I did this, put the scanPage.IsScanning = false; to prevent the twice reader

```
    ZXingScannerPage scanPage;
    SendData sd;

    private async void Btnpe001_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        sd = new SendData();

        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                sd.Action = "personentry";
                sd.DataToSend = result.Text;
                await sd.SendAsync();

                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                await DisplayAlert("Autenticado", result.Text, "OK");

            });
        };

    }
```

Comment: @I still want to be able to read on the scan of a new bar code but i want the pause function to be there i do not want to move off the page I did say that here your moving away from the page.